What's the correct way to build entities with parent / child relation with drupal
I'm asking myself on how to build a parent/child relation in a correct way.
First, the context...
I have two content entities, associated with two config entities. The parent entity is called "Exchange" and the child entity is "Exchange item".
"exchange item" is bundle of exchange_item_type, allowing to build exchange items of multiples types, like "ask a question", "refuse to answer", "answer the question", "give details", "validate answer".
The "exchange" is the parent entity who "hold" exchange items.
The goal is to build a system that allow (left) entities (ie users) starting an "exchange" and use a workflow to discuss with another (right) entity.
Example : User A initiate an exchange with User B and "ask a question". User B can "refuse to answer" or "answer the question". If he "refuse to answer", the exchange is marked as finished. If he "answer the question", User B can "give details" or "validate answer". If User B "give details", User A can "refuse to answer" or "answer the question", ...
I built the exchange_item (content) and exchange_item_type (config) entities, but actually I'm not sure how to create the relation between exchange_item and exchange entities.
Two solutions :

The exchange has an entity_reference field with cardinality = unlimited to store each exchange_item related to.

the exchange_item has an entity_reference field with cardinality = 1 to store the parent exchange related to.


What are pro and cons using the first or the second solution ? What is the default way usually taken to do this kind of relation ? I know that both solutions can be implemented, but maybe one is better than the other...
Thanks in advance for any answer pointing useful information.
